# Populating Multi Column listView with Database using Hashmap

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview, hashmap

I want to put all the columns of my table which is in database in a listview,ad I want to use Hashmap to make the columns,But I don't know where to put a loop for making new objects of map and putting the in a listview,When I run my application only the first column appears and it seems that other maps haven't been created yet!would you please help me?Thanks In Advance!

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#86868a"
    >
 <ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/CodeFont"
     >
    </ListView>
 <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >  
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/DeleteSelectedGoodsButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/DeleteSelectedGoods"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/ConfirmDelete"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/ConfirmDeleteButton"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/CancelButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/CancelButton"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     />
 </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

grids.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/GOOD_ID_CELL"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/CART_ID_CELL"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/GOOD_NAME_CELL"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/GOOD_UNITPRICE_CELL"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/QUANTITY_CELL"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />


    </LinearLayout>
```

SQLHelper:

```
package com.example.nfc;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public static String DB_PATH;
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;
    /////Adapted From spinner
     /** A constant, stores the the table name */

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Tbl_Goods";
    private static final String GOOD_ID = "Good_ID";
    private static final String CART_ID = "Cart_ID";
    private static final String GOOD_NAME = "Good_Name";
    private static final String GOOD_UNITPRICE = "Good_UnitPrice";
    private static final String QUANTITY = "Quantity";
    ////---------------------------

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return database;

    }

    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
        //-------------------------------------------------
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_NAME = databaseName;
        openDataBase();
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        // ----------------------------------------------
        //------------------- assets----------------------
        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // ----------------------------------------------------------
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // -------------------------------------------------
        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //------------------------------------
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        // -----------------------------
        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    ////-----------------------Adapted From SQLSpinner
    /** Inserts a new contact to the table contacts */
    public long insert(ContentValues contentValues){
        long rowID = database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return rowID;

    }

    /** Updates a contact */
    public int update(ContentValues contentValues,String contactID){
        int cnt = database.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "_id=" + contactID, null);
        return cnt;
    }

    /** Deletes a contact from the table */
    public int del(String contactID){
        int cnt = database.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id="+contactID, null);      
        return cnt;
    }

    /** Returns all the contacts in the table */
    public Cursor getAllContacts(){
        return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { GOOD_ID,  CART_ID , GOOD_NAME,GOOD_UNITPRICE,QUANTITY } , null, null, null, null, GOOD_NAME + " asc ");
    }

    /** Returns a contact by passing its id */
    public Cursor getContactByID(String contactID){
        return database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {  GOOD_ID,  CART_ID , GOOD_NAME,GOOD_UNITPRICE,QUANTITY} , "_ID="+contactID, null, null, null, GOOD_NAME + " asc ");
    }

    ////-----------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
}
```

Main.java:

```
package com.example.nfc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PrepopSqliteDbActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "NFC.sqlite";
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Tbl_Goods";
    private static final String GOOD_ID = "Good_ID";
    private static final String CART_ID = "Cart_ID";
    private static final String GOOD_NAME = "Good_Name";
    private static final String GOOD_UNITPRICE = "Good_UnitPrice";
    private static final String QUANTITY = "Quantity";

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ListView listView;
    //private ArrayList<String> goods;

    ///Adapted from MultiLevel

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> goods=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;


    //////-----------------Adapted From SQLSpinner
    ArrayAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.table_row);

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
        //--------------------------------------

        fillgoods();

        setUpList();  
  //////Cancel Button

        Button btnCancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.CancelButton);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                finish();
            }
        });


    }

    private void setUpList() {
        ///////////////////////////////////Multi
        //SimpleAdapter mSchedule=new SimpleAdapter(this, goods, R.layout.grids,
                //new String[]{"train","from","to"},
                //new int[]{R.id.TRAIN_CELL,R.id.FROM_CELL,R.id.TO_CELL});

        setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, goods, R.layout.grids,
                new String[]{GOOD_ID,CART_ID,GOOD_NAME,GOOD_UNITPRICE,QUANTITY},
                new int[]{R.id.GOOD_ID_CELL,R.id.CART_ID_CELL,R.id.GOOD_NAME_CELL,R.id.GOOD_UNITPRICE_CELL,
                R.id.QUANTITY_CELL}));

        //---------------------------------layout------------------------------------


        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(this,
                    //  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, goods));

        listView = getListView();
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);



        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position,long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            ((TextView) view).getText().toString(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
            }

        });


    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void fillgoods() {
        goods = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Cursor goodCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,
                                             new String[] 
                                             {GOOD_ID,CART_ID,GOOD_NAME,GOOD_UNITPRICE,QUANTITY},
                                             null, null, null, null
                                             , GOOD_NAME);


        String[] g=new String[] 
                 {GOOD_ID,CART_ID,GOOD_NAME,GOOD_UNITPRICE,QUANTITY};
        goodCursor.moveToFirst();
        if(!goodCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                int i=0;
                String name1 = goodCursor.getString(i+1);
                 map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                 map.put(g[i],name1);
                 goods.add(map);
                i=i+1;
            } while (goodCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        //goods.add(map);
        goodCursor.close();
    }


    //////////////Home And Back Button
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
       this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
      super.onAttachedToWindow();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)

           BackToMainIntent();

     else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
       {
         BackToMainIntent();
      }
       return false;
    }



    public void BackToMainIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
           startActivity(intent);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just facing problem in looping then change your old code to this one.

**Declare "i" before the do-while loop to fetch all the rows.** You had declared it inside the do-while loop that's why it was returning first row only.

```
 if(!goodCursor.isAfterLast()) {
       int i=0; //declare "i" here.
                do {
                    //int i=0;
                    String name1 = goodCursor.getString(i+1);
                     map=new HashMap<String, String>();
                     map.put(g[i],name1);
                     goods.add(map);
                    i=i+1;
                } while (goodCursor.moveToNext());
            }
```

Hope this will give you some hint about how to loop the records.